# using @PreAuthorize on interface declaration

Tags: java, spring-security

I have the following interface:

`TestInterface.java`

```
@PreAuthorize("hasAuthority('interface')")
public interface TestInterface {

    @PreAuthorize("hasAuthority('test')")
    public String testMethod();

}
```

And it's implementation:

`TestInterfaceImpl.java`

```
public class TestInterfaceImpl implements TestInterface {

    @Override
    public String testMethod() {
        return "testing";
    }

}
```

I wish to allow access to `testMethod` only to whom have in authorities: interface and test - how can i give permission to access an interface with `@PreAuthorize` because it only works on methods. The annotation written above the interface declaration is ignored.

Is it possible to use spring authorization annotations on interfaces like on methods?

Comment: `@PreAuthorize("hasAuthority('test')")` overrides the "global one". If you create a new method without any `@PreAuthorize` restriction, it will use the current one defined for the "whole" interface. Your current roles allowed definition has not an "AND behaviour".

Comment: Thanks for your answer, i thought if there is @PreAuthorize on interface and method they will be evaluated with AND when invoking the method but it is not.